# *PySpark* TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am working on this PySpark project, and when I am trying to calculate something, I get the following error:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'

I tried following the solution from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181617/getting-int-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-column-apache-spark) on this problem, but it did not work out for me. Anyway, please find my code below. I am fairly new to PySpark, therefore I would love to ask the community for help.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

start_month =(
    df
        .select('client_id')
        .withColumn("acquisition_month",
                    (datetime.datetime.today() - relativedelta(months = (df['months_since_act']).cast("integer")))
                   )
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is your whole code? Because there is no call of `int` in here!

Comment: it's not the whole code, it's just one of the cells in Jupyter. what do you mean by call of int?

Comment: Well...if it's not the whole code, and not even the whole relevant code or even the line where the error occurs, how should we help you?

Comment: this is the relevant code, the error occurs on the last line

Comment: Where exactly does it occur?

Comment: when I'm trying to run it, it points to the last line(datetime.datetime.today() - relativedelta(months = (df['months_since_act']).cast("integer")))

Comment: so I'm assuming the syntax is wrong, but I don't know how to make it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objective is to subtract number of days from the current date, where number of days is stored in another column, i can think of this approximate solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn("acquisition_month", expr("date_sub(current_date, months_since_act * 30 )"))
```

It is approximate in the sense that it treats a month to have exactly 30 days.

The error you are getting is because `relativedelta` expects the argument to be integer, but you are passing a column `df['months_since_act']`.

Comment: that's where I'm trying to get, do you know if there's any way to give it the data inside for every element rather than the whole thing at a time?

Comment: @MirunaPîrvulescu What do you mean by `give it the data inside for every element`?

Comment: "for every client_id, how can I calculate the date when an account was activated, given today's date and the number of months ago when the account was created?"

Comment: that is what I meant by that, sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: @MirunaPîrvulescu The code i posted should do that, since the withColumn transformation will be applied on each row of the DataFrame.

Comment: I gave it another run, my spark context was a little upset with me when I first ran it, but it works like a charm! thank you very much!

Comment: @MirunaPîrvulescu You are welcome. I am glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are passing a Column Type to relativedelta function, df['months_since_act'] returns Column type, not int

```
relativedelta(months = (df['months_since_act']).cast("integer"))
```

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve.

However, syntax should be like this when casting a column type to integer in spark

```
relativedelta(months = (df['value'].cast(IntegerType())))
```

Example for a UDF -

```
def getDelta(month):
  return datetime.datetime.today() - relativedelta(months = month)

delta = udf(lambda z: getDelta(z), IntegerType())

start_month =(
    df.select('client_id')
        .withColumn("acquisition_month",delta(df['months_since_act'].cast(IntegerType())))
                  )
```

I did not test it though but this will give you an idea.

Comment: thanks! in the 'months_since_act' column I have the number of months in the past when a client activated their account, and I'm trying to get that data (which is of type int) to calculate an approximate date when the account was created

Comment: I also tried putting it in that form and I'm getting the same error

Comment: I suggest you to write udf for the same.

Comment: Edited comment. added UDF example.

Comment: This is helping a lot, I'm trying to work on it now (y)